# Custom index not showing in the index manager popup

Tags: content-search, lucene

I have inherited a very old and messy instance of Sitecore 7.  Ive decided to cleanup some of the config files and im starting with the indexes.  There are a few custom indexes that i noticed don't show in the index manager popup.  I presume because the below declaration uses Sitecore search and not Lucene.  Does anyone know, if there is a way i can get them to appear?

```
 <configuration type="Sitecore.Search.SearchConfiguration, Sitecore.Kernel" singleinstance="true">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
         <index id="centresearch" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
           <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
           <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
           <analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
           <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
            <web type="Global.Application.Search.CentreSearchCrawler, Global.Application">
                <Database>web</Database>
                <Tags>web content</Tags>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/Global/Centres</Root>
            </web>
           </locations>
         </index>
        </indexes>
     </configuration>
```

Comment: `Sitecore.Search.Index` type was used in Sitecore 6. You can try changing it to `Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex` and update all the require properties like `configuration` and `strategies`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configuration should look like this one :

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
   <contentSearch>
    <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
      <index id="centersearch" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
        <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
        <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration" />
        <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
          <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
          <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
        </strategies>
        <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
            <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ModificationCountCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <Limit>300</Limit>
            </policy>
          </policies>
        </commitPolicyExecutor>
        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>web</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/Global/Centres</Root>
          </crawler>
        </locations>
      </index>
    </indexes>
  </configuration>
  </contentSearch>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I  remarked you have a custom crawler, you should modify

```
    <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
```

with you custom crawler class

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that i get an error when i add my custom crawler to the crawler node.  I suspect its because the custom crawler class inreits from the wrong base class.  It inherits from Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler not SitecoreItemCrawler

Comment: Can you add crawler code to the question?